# unknown type in catch at AXIOS request

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I have created a custom error and set a custom message for it. then somewhere I throw my custom error and catch somewhere else. I want to access to message that I set before .but TypeScript tell me that error has unknown type!
how can I fix it?

```
async activeAccount(uuid: string) {
  try {
    const response = await ApiClient(
      METHODS.GET,
      "Account/approveEmail",
      false,
      {
        uuid
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    this.showToastError(error.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the thing caught by `catch` is actually an error because `throw` can throw *anything* (that's why the type is `unknown`, you *have* to narrow it with checks to do anything with it). The compiler is warning you appropriately that you are failing to consider something like this:

```js
try {
    throw undefined;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message); // oops
}
```

to fix this, you can add a check to make sure that you have an actual error:

```js
try {
    ...
} catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
        console.log(err.message); // ok
    }
}
```